# Wordpress crashes when I click add new plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-list-table

I recently uninstalled the plugin [SEO Facebook Comments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-facebook-comments/)

Since then when I click on add new plugin I get this error,

> Warning: require_once(D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugin-install-list-table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu\wp-admin\includes\list-table.php on line 42
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugin-install-list-table.php' (include_path='D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu\wp-content\plugins\google-analyticator\google-api-php-client\src;.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu\wp-admin\includes\list-table.php on line 42

I've looked for this error on google and this site although I cannot seem to find anyone else with this error?

Can anyone suggest on how I can get past this?

Comment: This is a pretty explicit PHP error `No such file or directory`

Comment: Okay sorry I've never seen this before? How can I fix it? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It sounds like your copy of WP Core is now incomplete. I hope you haven't been making modifications to it, and you can restore the relevant file from backups or by downloading the appropriate version of WordPress and copying the wp-admin folder over the top of your install

Comment: Yeah I didn't do any modifications, oh well I had to restore from a previous backup.